# JSF pages with tables

Tags: jsf, memory, datatable

Is it normal to have multiple pages with datatables in a relatively high load environment? We plan to have >20 pages with tables and each table gets data from a bean in view scope, there will be >50 concurrently working users.
I read that beans in a view scope are not disposed when navigating to another page in order to support work with multiple tabs in a browser. So, will such a design lead to mallocs?

Comment: Measuring is knowing. Memory is cheap these days.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just wanted to know that the time spent on development such JSF application is not useless when I start load tests after it is completed.